# Securing Application Pages

Tags: active-directory, application-pages, access-denied, roles, authorization

I have a set of application pages stored in the _layouts virtual directory, that I'd like to secure, in order to prevent **unauthorized access** to the pages, as well as **prevent** certain **actions** from being **executed**.

My authorization structure consists of several **AD Security Groups** (although this is somewhat *flexible*, and I could create the groups in SharePoint), each of which, will have a set of application pages that they can access, and actions within each page that the user can execute. Something along these lines:

```
User Group | Access to Application Pages | Actions
-----------+-----------------------------+-----------------------------------------
A          | Page1.aspx, Page2.aspx      | Page1.aspx->Button1, Page2.aspx->Button2
-----------+-----------------------------+-----------------------------------------
B          | Page1.aspx                  | Page1.aspx->Button3
-----------+-----------------------------+-----------------------------------------
```

An [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd878359%28v=office.12%29.aspx) on MSDN, suggests using `SPRoleDefinition`s, and verify at `Page_PreLoad`, for example, if a user has the required roles to access the page, and if not, redirect him to `accessdenied.aspx`. The same could be done for the actions within each page. However, this solution would require me to drop AD Groups, and store users and groups in SharePoint.

Another solution would be to add `location` tags to the `web.config` with `allow` and `deny`, although this solution doesn't solve the problem of preventing actions within each page from being executed.

```
  <location path="_layouts/Page1.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow roles="AD\A,AD\B" />
```

**How** can this type of scenario be accomplished? **What** is the typical configuration used in SharePoint solutions for this use case?

Comment: Why are you using application pages? For you scenario it seems to me, that it would be easier to have site pages and secure them by "item level security" (in which you could use your AD groups). However, to secure the actions within the pages you have to code something on your own.

Comment: @marco: Because it's essentially an aspx custom application built on top of SharePoint.

Comment: You can still divide the aspx application into usercontrols and place these user controls on a page layout and create site pages using these layouts. 
Also is there a specific reason why you want to use the aspx application AS-IS, without converting it into a proper integrated SharePoint App.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up with a solution loosely based on the concept of *Role Definitions* presented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd878359%28v=office.12%29.aspx). Here's a brief description of how this was implemented.

For every AD Security Group, create an `SPGroup`, whose sole member is the corresponding directory group. Then, create an `SPRoleDefinition` for each required page access, e.g., `Page_1.aspx - Read`, and an `SPRoleAssignment` to link the roles to the sharepoint groups. This can be easily done within a *bootstrap* feature receiver.

After that, roles can be accessed using the `AllRolesForCurrentUser` property of `SPWeb`.

Then, in order to **hide** the navigation links from the menu, preventing users who do not have the required roles from viewing them, I implemented a custom `SiteMapProvider`, overriding the `IsAccessibleToUser`, to use the roles obtained in the aforementioned property. Something along these lines (simplified; in a production environment, you'd use caching, etc.):

```
    public override bool IsAccessibleToUser(HttpContext context, SiteMapNode node)
    {
        var roles = node.Roles.OfType<string>();
        if (roles.Contains("*")) {
            return true;
        } else {
            SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Web;
            SPRoleDefinitionBindingCollection allUserRoles = web.AllRolesForCurrentUser;
            foreach (string role in roles) {
                SPRoleDefinition requiredRole = web.RoleDefinitions[role];
                if (allUserRoles.contains(requiredRole)) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Finally, in order to actually **prevent** users from **accessing** the page, make every ApplicationPage extend from a base page, whose `OnInit` event basically verifies that the current site map node is accessible to the user, and if not, redirects the user to the access denied page:

```
    protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (SiteMap.CurrentNode == null) {
            SPUtility.Redirect(SPUtility.AccessDeniedPage, SPRedirectFlags.RelativeToLayoutsPage,
                this.Context, "ReturnUrl=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Context.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

> I've read an article on MSDN, that suggests using SPRoleDefinitions,
>   and verify at Page_PreLoad, for example, if a user has the required
>   roles to access the page, and if not, redirect him to
>   accessdenied.aspx. The same could be done for the actions within each
>   page. However, this solution would require me to drop AD Groups, and
>   store users and groups in SharePoint.

This is what we do on a large number of our apps.  For each AD group make a Sharepoint group, and put the AD group in the sharepoint group as the only "user".  After that everything else in that paragraph should work out just fine.

Comment: Point of clarification, those AD groups must be Security groups, not Distribution lists, in order to be imported and used in SharePoint groups.

Comment: @Servy: Thank you very much for your feedback. I have a question though. By putting the AD group as a member of the SharePoint group, this will give access to SharePoint for all users that belong to the AD group, which is perfect. However, when authenticated with such a user, will the `SPUser` object have access to the SharePoint Group that is the "parent" of its AD Group? Or will I have to run a custom query to the AD to find out this mapping? Thanks.

Comment: @John I don't think that those relationships will be maintained, no.